# ActionBar Navigation Tabs - Main Activity Layout for Tab?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, tabs

I have great problems getting the Navigation Tabs work. I am aware of this guide http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs
but I have problems understanding the article. It says the following:

> To get started, your layout must include a ViewGroup in which you place each Fragment associated with a tab. Be sure the ViewGroup has a resource ID so you can reference it from your code and swap the tabs within it. Alternatively, if the tab content will fill the activity layout, then your activity doesn't need a layout at all (you don't even need to call setContentView()). Instead, you can place each fragment in the default root view, which you can refer to with the android.R.id.content ID.

As I don't use a Fragment for my Main Layout, but for others, I think the "alternative" way is right for me (I would like Tab 1 to be the Main Layout I have right now and then 2 and 3 to be my fragments), but I don't know how to accomplish this. Can someone maybe help out on this?
I was able to set up the tabs and the TabListener, so that is not the problem. The problem is that the first tab is NOT supposed to be a fragment, but my main activity layout! This is where I need help!

I did try to use my main activity-layout for a fragment, but for some reason if I click that tab, the tab changes but the screen stays white. I cannot see my fragment view.
The old code was:

```
mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
mListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

and I've changed it in the fragment to:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, container, false);
mListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
mListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
// do stuff here //
return view;
```

and this is list.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android:="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@id/main_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout:height=match_parent">
    <ListView android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout:height=0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout:marginTop="20dp"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

how come I cannot see anything?

---

**Solved:** This was because I set the height to 0dp.

Comment: you can use a `ViewPager` with `Fragments` for tab-based navigation. `The problem is that the first tab is NOT supposed to be a fragment, but my main activity layout` - why not use this layout for the 1st `Fragment`?

Comment: I tried that, but for some reason I am not able to see the ListView my main-layout existed of this way (I edited the question to explain what I did)

Comment: why is your layout's height set to 0dp? remove the `weight` attribute and set the height to `match_parent`

Comment: oh boy! this actually was the problem. don't know how this happened! thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Please update your code by this:

```
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android:="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/main_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout:height=match_parent">
            <ListView android:id="@+id/list_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"/>
        </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: remove weight fields which is not required in this by which you are not able to see any view

Comment: That could indeed be the solution! Please add your explanation to your answer.